# Access to ReflectedType of PropertyInfo when unboxing from Object

Tags: c#, reflection

Lets assume that I have some PropertyInfo object created from reflection process.

Normally I can get type of internal object via its ReflectedType property. But if it was boxed  into object i just can't access it.

```
var x = property.ReflectedType //Works as charm
var y = ((object)property).ReflectedType // Wouldn't work
```

How should I access to ReflectedType property of PropertyInfo that was boxed to object?

Comment: What are you really trying to accomplish? You must also be aware that you are not "unboxing" but `casting`. An entirely different process :)

Comment: have smth like this. ((object)property) need to know property.ReflectedType

Comment: If you have found an answer to your problem please post it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure your `object` references a `PropertyInfo`, then cast back to `PropertyInfo` and you can access the property.

```
var z = ((PropertyInfo)y).ReflectedType
```

Edit regarding your additional comment on the quesion: if you still have access to your property variable where you want to do it, then just use that... I feel like you are confused about something here, but you should provide more information, because no one can help you unless you do.

Comment: `private static void SetPropertyValue(object v, XElement item, PropertyInfo property)  
        {
            switch (property.PropertyType.Name)
            {
                case "UInt64":
                    property.SetValue(v, Convert.ToUInt64(item.Value), null);
                    break;
                case "UInt32":
                    property.SetValue(v, Convert.ToUInt32(item.Value), null);
                    break;
                default:
                    property.SetValue(v, item.Value, null);
                    break;
            }
      }`  v is of type RuntimePropertyInfo

Comment: @PaulKyrejto Then can you add this code to your question with an explanation of what you actually want to do instead of a synthetic code snippet? Do you want to access a property of this `RuntimePropertyInfo`? You only need to cast to it then.

Answer (score 0):

When reading your comment on @fish's answer this is probably what you want to do:

```
private static void SetPropertyValue(object v, XElement item, PropertyInfo property)
{
  property.SetValue(v, Convert.ChangeType(item.Value, property.PropertyType));
}
```

Does that help?